# How to remove an specific href from a top-menu link in magento?

Tags: theme, menu, category-tree

I have an specific cateogry (top-level / main category) witch shows a menu on hover at menu.
I need to remove the href from that < li> item, or replace href value for "javascript:void(0);".

I'm trying to do this with *page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before* and *page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_after* observers, but didn't get it yet.

I wouln't like to make a replace in block's html output. I don't think it's a good idea. =O

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove url, href functionality of the top menu categories, you can take the following steps:

1. Create some folder as this path: `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block`
2. Copy file Navigation.php from a`pp/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block` to  `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block`
3. Go to `function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()`

**Replace this code**

```
$html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
$html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
$html[] = '</a>';
```

**with this code**

```
if($category->getLevel()== 2 && $hasActiveChildren) {
            $html[] = '<a href="[removed]void(0);"'.$linkClass.'>';
            $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
            $html[] = '</a>';
} else {
            $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
            $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
            $html[] = '</a>';
}
```

Comment: I found this post because i needed this solution too... and it works great... however... it creates an issue in mobile menu... how to solve that?

In the mobile menu the Menu Item that has it's linked removed in normal view is a link again, leading to a 404 page now.